# What is the difference between dragging an object or it's controller on a xib view?

Tags: iphone, xcode, ios, ios4, xib

In xcode what is the difference between dragging a Table View vs dragging a Table View Controller on a view in a xib?

Same thing with dragging a Tab Bar vs a Tab Bar Controller?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `UITableView` is a view that must be hooked up to a controller somewhere in order to control it's contents, while a `UITableViewController` is a pre-built controller that you can subclass that has a table view.

A tab bar needs a controller as well, and `UITabBarController` provides a pre-built controller. You can also build your own.